# Default value for @Value for all properties

Tags: spring, properties, default-value

If we don't have a value for a property we get below error. This error can be avoided by setting a colon `:` with or without a default value. Is there a way we can set default value for all the properties that way my application need not rely on the developer to specify `:`?

`Could not resolve placeholder`

If there is a better approach to solve this, please let me know.

```
@Component
public class PropertiesDemo {

    @Value("${some.key1:my default here}")
    private String stringWithDefaultValue;

    @Value("${some.key2:}")
    private String stringWithBlankDefaultValue;

    @Value("${some.key3:}")
    private Boolean booleanWithBlankDefaultValue;

    @Value("${some.key4:}")
    private Integer intWithBlankDefaultValue;

    @PostConstruct
    public void printValues() {
        System.out.println("stringWithDefaultValue :: "+stringWithDefaultValue);
        System.out.println("stringWithBlankDefaultValue :: "+stringWithBlankDefaultValue);
        System.out.println("booleanWithBlankDefaultValue :: "+booleanWithBlankDefaultValue);
        System.out.println("intWithBlankDefaultValue :: "+intWithBlankDefaultValue);
    }

}
```

```
stringWithDefaultValue :: my default here
stringWithBlankDefaultValue :: 
booleanWithBlankDefaultValue :: null
intWithBlankDefaultValue :: null
```

Comment: Could you please add your code ?

Comment: There is no standard way of setting a default. What would the default be for an int, long, String, map... All those properties can be converted into something else. While `foobar` might be a valid default for a `String` how would that become a default for a numeric type?

Comment: @MukeshKeshu, @M. Deinum, I added a working code snippet above. If you run this in any spring application, it will print the output as shown above. In the above example, if developer forgets to put ```:```, the application will not startup. Is there a way we can setup default values to all the properties? With the above pattern Spring is taking the datatype of the field declared to choose the default value.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @M.Deinum, there is no standard way of doing that.

Conversion between types is usually covered by `Converter` implementations. The use case here is a bit unusual and there must be more to it in your particular case.

You might be interested in [type-safe configuration properties in Spring Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) which provide default values directly on the type, rich types, validation, binding from the environment.

Comment: how about any of these options? 1) Can we catch ```Could not resolve placeholder values``` exception and handle it appropriately without server startup failure?             2) How about using ```@ConfigurationProperties``` and using ```@Validated``` at class level. This way I can implement a validator so that server startup is not impacted? My end goal is I do not want to stop the server but rather catch such invalid properties exceptions and handle appropriately. I use config server and hence I can always update the properties file to correct values if the server starts up.